# Try catch is not being executed in second time

Tags: android, android-intent, try-catch

I have  a class sifaris_Main containing tab layout. try-catch code is below:

```
try {
     Intent intent = getIntent();
         id = intent.getExtras().getString("sifarisId");
     } catch (Exception e) {
         Log.e("errorasdsad", e.toString());
     }
```

first when this page is being called, the try catch code is executed. Since nothing is being passed in intent in first time, it shows null pointer exception which is handled by catch statement.
And i have a second class `sifarish_Description`. Here

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(sifarish_Description.this, sifaris_Main.class);
    intent.putExtra("sifarisId", sifarisId);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

As the intent forces it to return back to `sifarish_main` class, it should have executed `try-catch` block again. but that `try-catch` block is not being executed. Can somebody please help me?

Comment: where is your 2nd try catch? can you post more of your code

Comment: add try catch code in onResume() method

Comment: This architecture seems broken. If you want to return something from `sifarish_Description` to `sifaris_Main` then you should have `sifaris_Main` launch `sifarish_Description` using `startActivityForResult()`. Then, in `onBackPressed()` you just need to call `setResult()` and `finish()` and the data will be passed back to the existing instance of `sifarish_Main` in `onActivityResult()`.

Comment: Also, using `try/catch` for this purpose is really a bad idea. You should check for `null` in the specific places where you expect that and not assume that any exception thrown means that there are no "extras" in the `Intent`. This is really bad programming style.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because you have placed your code with try catch in the onCreate() method. If you put this block in onResume() method, then it will be executed since onResume() method is called if the activity starts the first time and even when you return to the activity from another activity which is happening in your case. I hope this helps.

**EDIT:**
Looks like your are recreating the activity and onResume() would not help. So its better you finish the **sifaris_Main** actviity when you navigate to **sifarish_Description** activity by calling finish() after startActivity(intent):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(sifaris_Main.this, sifarish_Description.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

By the look of your requirement you need this code block as well, place this in your onBackPressed() method:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(sifarish_Description.this, sifaris_Main.class);
    intent.putExtra("sifarisId", sifarisId);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Basically the third line clears the activity from backstack and starts a new task.

Comment: I tried using onResume method but it is being executed only in first time. second time when i return back to that activity the method is not being called.
my code is below
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        try {
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            id = intent.getExtras().getString("sifarisId");
            Log.e("errorasdsad", id = "");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("errorasdsad", e.toString());
        }
    }

Comment: just found out that onResume is being executed both time i.e when that activity is being called and on being returned. But on second time try-Catch is not being executed.